# Java project to identify palindrome number is returning false with matching output

Tags: java

I am three weeks into  learning programming and this is my first time on stack overflow. I have run into an issue on a course project. I'm meant to take a number and return true if it is a palindrome. It appears that if I enter a number with an even number of digits, my while loop correctly identifies the number as a palindrome or not. If the number I plug in has an odd number of digits then the loop spits out a number that matches the input but returns false to the method. I've moved stuff around and tried changing requirements for my while loop with varying results but can't figure this issue out. I can access other students completed code to change mine and finish the project but I want to understand whatever it is that I'm not understanding.

public class Main {

```
public static void main ( String [] args ) {
    System.out.println ( isPalindrome ( 111 ) ) ;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome ( int number ) {

    int lastDigit = 0 ;
    int reverseNumber = 0 ;

    while ( number != 0 ) {
        lastDigit = ( number % 10 ) ;
        reverseNumber = reverseNumber * 10 + lastDigit ;
        number /= 10 ;
        System.out.println ( reverseNumber ) ;
        if ( reverseNumber == number ) {
            return true ;
        }
    }
    return false ;
}
```

}

I'm printing my variable "reverseNumber" to see if my output matches my input. I also have no knowledge of arrays or anything Math.whatever so I'm looking for pretty bare bones help. Thanks for helping me through my admittedly pathetic problem.

Comment: With an odd number of digits, reverseNumber will never equal number.

Comment: You should really use a debugger on this, or run this through with pen and paper to see why this algorithm doesn't work for odd numbers of digits. BlueJ has an easy debugger and its free.

Comment: NomadMaker, I haven't really gotten into using a debugger or anything like that. Im writing my code in eclipse and I know that there is a debugger available there. When you say BlueJ has an easy debugger do you mean that it's easier for a new user to figure out or would I be better served by running the debugger in my selected IDE?

Comment: I would try the debugger in eclipse first, if one is available. There are many tutorials on the web in how to use it.

Comment: Great, thanks. That'd probably be the best way to start solving my own problems more effectively. I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main ( String [] args ) {
    System.out.println ( isPalindrome ( 111 ) ) ;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome ( int number ) {

    int lastDigit = 0 ;
    int reverseNumber = 0 ;
    int num = number;

    while ( num != 0 ) {
        lastDigit = ( num % 10 ) ;
        reverseNumber = reverseNumber * 10 + lastDigit ;
        num /= 10 ;
        System.out.println ( reverseNumber ) ;
        if ( reverseNumber == number ) {
            return true ;
        }
    }
    return false ;
}
```

you are changing your number every time and in the end comparing it to reversed value which will be 111==0, just store your original value in some temp varialbe lets say num.

Comment: He did that to check for a palindrome, but it fails for numbers with an odd number of digits.

Comment: check is not valid and it will not work for any number, since in the end `number` will become 0 and `reverseNumber` will become reverse of that. so, `reverseNumber == number` will always be fasle. You should not change value of `reverseNumber == number` and for that use a temporary varilable like `int num= number` and use that.

Comment: It is equal for palindrome numbers with an even number of digits. This is a homework problem, so I've been trying to avoid answering the question.

Comment: So I want to make sure I understand why that was causing my issue. My output was the same as the input but that was just because I was printing from inside my while loop. When the program jumped out of the while loop I was then comparing the number to nothing and so returned false. But why was it working if the number I entered had an even number of digits? That's the part that is the most confusing to me. Was it just a fluke that those numbers were returning true?

Comment: for even number of digit...while reversing the number there comes a point when it divides number exactly in half eg. if number is 1111 then after 2 iterations reverse would be 11 and number would be 11. hence it returns true.